# ¿Como cambiar el segundo caracter igual de un string en sqlserver?

Tags: sql, sql-server

En una consulta de `sqlServer` hago un select de un campo que tiene espacios y hago en `replace` de los espacios para convertirlos en guiones bajos o "underlines" y hasta ahi todo funciona bien, el problema es que necesito cambiar el segundo guion bajo o "underline" por una coma? como podría hacer esto?

**CONSULTA**

```
SELECT REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(dbo.MAEMED1.MMNomM)), ' ', '_') AS NAME FROM dbo.MAEMED1
```

**EJEMPLO**

La consulta con esta sentencia muestra **LOPEZ_MOLINA_JAVIER_EMILIO**
y seria cambiarlo de tal manera que arroje **LOPEZ_MOLINA,JAVIER_EMILIO**

Agradecería el interés

Comment: Se agradecería enormemente que incluyeras un dato de entrada y la salida esperada

Comment: @Alfabravo, listo ya lo he cambiado :D

Comment: Acabo de ver que has puesto lo de la coma en medio, pensaba que querías separar la cadena. Cambio mi respuesta ya

Answer (score 0):

La función [charindex](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) te permite buscar la **primera ocurrencia** de un carácter. Si la buscas inicialmente, y vuelves a realizar la función pero sumando 1 a la posición encontrada en el primer charindex, puedes buscar la segunda posición sin problema. A partir de ahí, es fácil hacer un [substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

**EDIT**

> Inicialmente pensaba que necesitabas partir los nombres. En el caso de
>   sustituir por la coma, puedes usar la función [STUFF](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) que elimnina X
>   caracteres en la posición que desees, y los sustituye por una cadena
>   de texto.

**para sustituir por la coma**

```
SELECT STUFF( 
  REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM('LOPEZ MOLINA JAVIER EMILIO')), ' ', '_')
  , CHARINDEX('_', REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM('LOPEZ MOLINA JAVIER EMILIO')), ' ', '_'),CHARINDEX('_', REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM('LOPEZ MOLINA JAVIER EMILIO')), ' ', '_'),1)+1)
  ,1,',')
```

[Aquí el ejemplo bueno](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/85761)

**El resultado**
[image: El resultado]

**Haciendo replace:**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM('LOPEZ MOLINA JAVIER EMILIO')), ' ', '_'), CHARINDEX('_', REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM('LOPEZ MOLINA JAVIER EMILIO')), ' ', '_'), CHARINDEX('_', REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM('LOPEZ MOLINA JAVIER EMILIO')), ' ', '_'),0 )+1)+1,LEN(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM('LOPEZ MOLINA JAVIER EMILIO')), ' ', '_')))
```

**Sin replace**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM('LOPEZ MOLINA JAVIER EMILIO')), CHARINDEX(' ', RTRIM(LTRIM('LOPEZ MOLINA JAVIER EMILIO')), CHARINDEX(' ', RTRIM(LTRIM('LOPEZ MOLINA JAVIER EMILIO')),0 )+1),LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM('LOPEZ MOLINA JAVIER EMILIO'))) )
```

El [SQLFiddle De ejemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ef4d3/32)